# Is this "hung" an intransitive verb or a linking verb?

Tags: verbs, intransitive-verbs, linking-verbs

> From the ceiling hung the chandelier.

I could not decide whether *hung* in the previous sentence is a linking verb or an action verb.

Should we rearrange this sentence to see it more easily?

Comment: What about "On the floor stood the table"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intransitive verb because the chandelier hung from the ceiling and from the ceiling is not a direct object no matter how you place it.